# How to change frame title font color in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts, color

Is there a way to change the frame title font color in between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`? I would like this frame title to be a different font color than the rest of the frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `frametitle` beamer color. If you do this within a group it won't change the other frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=blue,fg=red}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
normal text
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
normal text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent of ```\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=blue,fg=red}``` for the frame's body font?

Comment: @curry For the body, you could simply use `\color{green}` at the start of the frame